# Highcharts Highmaps display tooltip of bubbles under datalabels

Tags: highcharts

I built a map with two series, one of them a map bubble. See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Joh_Christ/ynxbteas/2/)

```
                  dataLabels: {
                          enabled: true,
                          useHTML: true,
                          allowOverlap: true,
                          x: 0,
                          y: 0,
                          formatter: function() {
                          if (this.point.bl == "Niedersachsen") {
                                    return '<div align="center" style="line-height: 110%">' + this.point.bl + '<br><b>' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.point.inf, 0) + ' • <span style="color: #b30012">' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.point.tot, 0) + '</b></span></div>';
                          } 
                          else {
                              return null;
                          }
                      },
```

Unfortunately the tooltip of the bubbles is not displayed under the datalabels of the other series (Look at the datalabel "Saarland" at the screenshot - the mouse becomes a cursor). How can I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable `pointer-events` for data labels:

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    dataLabels: {
      ...,
      style: {
        ...,
        pointerEvents: 'none'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2j74enup/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/series.map.dataLabels.style

Comment: Thank you, @ppotaczek!